# Как получить HMID видеокарты из реестра?

Tags: c#, windows, реестр, видеокарта

Как на C# получить HMID видеокарты из реестра Windows?

Comment: А что такое HMID? Как расшифровывается?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что такое HMID, но, возможно, вот такое решение с помощью WMI может помочь:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace Test
{
    class Class1
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void main(string[] args)
        {
            ManagementScope sc = 
                        new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2", null);
            ManagementPath ph = 
                        new ManagementPath(@"Win32_VideoController");

            ManagementClass mc = 
                            new ManagementClass(sc, ph, null);

            foreach(ManagementObject ss in mc.getInstances())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", ss.getPropertyValue("Name"));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Источник: Павел Агуров "C#. Сборник рецептов." 
Так же в книге упоминаются свойства "VideoProcessor", "AdapterRAM", "VideoModeDescription", "CurrentRefreshRate", если нужно. У меня, к сожалению, возможности проверить решение нет.